# How do I say the term cold as in the sickness, in Japanese?

Tags: translation, meaning, words

I am using 鼻水 but it doesn't seem right. I wanted to find the term for a head cold.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it can be solved by a simple dictionary search.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be 「鼻{はな}かぜ」.

「鼻水｛はなみず｝」 means "snot", "runny nose", etc.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that かぜmeans wind? Thank you.

Comment: @JACKB No かぜ = 風邪 here. See http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6818/1628