# 風邪: reading and writing

Tags: kanji

Why do we write かぜ (cold) as 風邪, not just 風?

The second kanji (邪) is left unread, so why isn't it redundant?

Perhaps, that's to make sure cold doesn't sound like wind. But then why don't we read it in the word 風邪 (かぜ)?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6818/how-is-the-wind-related-to-illness

Comment: As a general principle, words of non-Chinese origin do not "have" *kanji*. Whatever *kanji* that they are written with are *assigned to them*. If they have been consistently assigned for a very long time, they are now accepted readings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

かぜ in the context of this question has two (related) meanings.

- The meaning *wind* is written as 風, because that's how you write *wind* in Chinese.
- The meaning *cold (sickness)* is written as 風邪, because that's how you write *cold (sickness)* in Chinese (or more specifically, Traditional Chinese medicine).

> The second kanji (邪) is left unread

This is not the correct way to think about it. All non-Chinese readings of *kanji* are basically Japanese translations of Chinese words. In principle, any *kanji* or a string of multiple *kanji* can be read with a Japanese translation that is etymologically distinct from the Chinese word the *kanji* represents.

- A Japanese translation-reading for a single character is called *kun'yomi*. Hence, かぜ is a *kun'yomi* for the character 風.
- A Japanese translation-reading for multiple characters is called *jukujikun* (if these readings are *established readings*). Hence, かぜ is a *jukujikun* for the *kanji string* 風邪.

  - The character representation of a *jukujikun* word does not necessarily have a morpheme correspondence between the Chinese characters and Japanese morphemes, so you cannot decompose 風邪 into Japanese morphemes. Hence, 風 in 風邪 is not read as かぜ, and 邪 is not "unread".